# Get file size of GIFs with node-canvas?

Tags: node.js, node-canvas

After much struggling, I've managed to get [node-canvas](https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas) installed on Windows.

When I try to read in the image size of a GIF, however, it just gives me back 0 for the width and height.

```
var FileSystem = require('fs');
var Canvas = require('canvas');

FileSystem.readdir(baseDir, function(err, files) {
    files.forEach(function(filename) {
        var path = Path.join(baseDir, filename);
        FileSystem.readFile(path, function(err, buf) {
            var img = new Canvas.Image;
            img.src = buf;
            console.log(path, img.width, img.height);
        });
});
```

Is it not supposed to be able to read GIFs?

Answer (score 1):

You must install giflib and reinstall node-canvas like is said in here https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---OSX and then you will be able to manipulate your gif file (retrieve width/height). But beware, the image processed with canvas will stop being animated.